# Flyway migration execution from jar file

Tags: java, maven, jar, flyway

I integrated flyway into a new project and if I execute the class throw the IDE, the migration works fine. But also I want to let the migration start over the jar file from command line. But if I build the project with maven and execute the jar file, I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/flywaydb/core/api/migration/jdbc/JdbcMigration
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at de.toom.controller.ContentMigrationApplication.main(ContentMigrationApplication.java:5)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.flywaydb.core.api.migration.jdbc.JdbcMigration
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

If I use the SpringJdbcMigration as mentioned in other threads, I get the same exception.

pom.xml:

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.sql</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.test.controller.ContentMigrationApplication</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <archive>
                <manifest>
                  <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                  <mainClass>com.test.controller.ContentMigrationApplication</mainClass>
                </manifest>
              </archive>
            </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <!-- External dependencies -->
    <!-- ====================================================================== -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
        <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.39</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

ContentMigrationApplication.java:

```
public class ContentMigrationApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ContentMysqlMigration contentMysqlMigration = new ContentMysqlMigration();

        contentMysqlMigration.migrateDatabase(args);
    }
}
```

ContentMysqlMigration.java

```
public class ContentMysqlMigration implements JdbcMigration {
    private static final String DATABASE_DRIVER_CONNECTION = "jdbc:mysql://";
    private static final String SERVER_ADDRESS = "localhost";
    private static final String SERVER_ADDRESS_PORT = ":3306";
    private static final String SERVER_DATABASE_NAME = "/test";
    private static final String SERVER_USERNAME = "test";
    private static final String SERVER_PASSWORD = "test";

    public ContentMysqlMigration() {}

    public void migrateDatabase(String[] args) {
        Flyway flyway = new Flyway();

        flyway.setBaselineOnMigrate(true);

        flyway.setDataSource(DATABASE_DRIVER_CONNECTION + SERVER_ADDRESS + SERVER_ADDRESS_PORT + SERVER_DATABASE_NAME,
                SERVER_USERNAME, SERVER_PASSWORD);

        flyway.migrate();
    }

    public void migrate(Connection connection) throws Exception {}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because your jar doesn't contains the dependencies.

You see `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/flywaydb/core/api/migration/jdbc/JdbcMigration`?

Your jar contains only the .class of your sources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
With maven, it should work, when I provide the dependency or? I defined a scope, but this doesn't work.
Either I tried to copy the sources to the resource folder and link them with my class, but with no result. The sources are in the jar file, but can't be found.

Comment: The easiest (dirtiest) way to do that is to use the maven shade plugin, it will create a uber jar with everything in it, and it should work for you